# show the fps of an app like cocos 2D

Tags: xcode, uikit, cocos2d-iphone, frames, frame-rate

I would like to know how can I show in my  application the **frames **(fps) like in cocos 2D at the bottom left corner of the screen.So I can see if my app is running at 60fps or 30fps.Sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score -1):

Go to your AppDelegate.m and do this

`[director setDisplayFPS:YES];`

If it doesn't work then refer this [link.](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/9594)

Comment: He wants to display it *like* in cocos2D. So he's got a "normal" UIKit app that he wants to display the FPS in.